# UI for displaying large amounts of hierachical data

Tags: responsive-design, treeview, hierarchical-data, usability

I have large amounts of data with a hierachical structure of arbitrary depth. I'm looking for a solution to display the data within a responsive single page application, so that the user can select any element within the hierarchy.

Right now I'm using a typical tree-control:

[image]

Since I have many data elements the usability of such a tree-control is really bad on devices with a small screen. Do you have any suggestions concerning the Layout of the User Interface that enriches the usability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An off-canvas menu is one option that could work for you.

On mobile it will give you much more screen space to display your links. It's becoming a more popular option on desktop now as well, or you could have off-canvas navigation on mobile and your tree menu on desktop.

There are plenty of good off-canvas solutions available, I've used [jQuery.mmenu](https://github.com/FrDH/jQuery.mmenu) on a single page page site with good results. It looks good, it's well documented, and it has plenty of configuration options.

Hope this helps!